# Not able to call global variable in nested if statement in javaScript

Tags: javascript

Can i anyone help right now i am not able to call a variable define in global inside a nested if demo code is given below
ps: here it is working but in my actual code at this place i am getting problem

```js
var demo = "hello";

var flag ="0";

if( flag == "0"){
  console.log('sucess' + demo); // i am getting this value
  if(flag == "0"){
    console.log(demo); // not able to access here
  }
  else {
  };
}
else{
}
```

Comment: Both the if and nested have the same conditions. No point of using nested ifs.

Comment: this is just a demo but in second loop i am not able to get data so can you tell why it may happen

Comment: var flag =="0"; this is the cause of the error u were comparing not assigning change the double  == to single = i.e var flag = "0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `var flag="0"` not `var flag=="0"`  .Its assignment not comparison.
Values are assigned using single  `=` operator while comparison uses `==` or `===` operators to compare values. Both aren't the same.

```js
var demo = "hello";

var flag ="0";

if( flag == "0"){
  console.log('sucess' + demo); // i am getting this value
  if(flag == "0"){
    console.log(demo); // not able to access here
  }
  else {
  };
}
else{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you get hello in the first place because you've used `"=="` which is used for comparison and `"="` used for assignment of a variable.

```js
var demo = "hello";

var flag ="0"; //now the value is assinged with help of "="

if( flag == "0"){ // compare value of flag with 0 with help of "==" 
  console.log('sucess' + demo); // i am getting this value
  if(flag == "0"){
    console.log(demo); // not able to access here
  }
  else {
  };
}
else{
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain what your code is doing

Comment: yup i've explained that  :)

Answer (score 1):

change var `flag == "0";` to var `flag = "0";`

Answer (score 0):

```
var demo = "hello";

var flag = 0;

if( flag === 0){
  console.log("sucess" + demo); 
  if(flag === 0){
    console.log(demo); 
  }
  else { }
}
else{ }
```

Comment: while declaration of flag use only one equal to to assign the value.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22045840)

Comment: Nick i have mention what was the mistake in the code with comment. see the below comment over there "while declaration of flag use only one equal to to assign the value" thanks .

Comment: That comment should be part of your answer. Compare your answer with the accepted answer and the other upvoted answer and you'll see they both have much more information in them.